# Read specific data from a Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a Firebase Database where I store users registered to my app.
Database structure is

[image]

My code retrieves all users saved to my database

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let database = Database.database().reference()
    let usuarios = database.child("usuarios")

    usuarios.observe(DataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let dados = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let autenticacao = Auth.auth()
        let idUsuarioLogado = autenticacao.currentUser?.uid

        let emailUsuario = dados?["email"] as! String
        let nomeUsuario = dados?["nome"] as! String
        let perfilUsuario = dados?["perfil"] as! String
        let idUsuario = snapshot.key

        let usuario = Usuario(email: emailUsuario, nome: nomeUsuario, uid: idUsuario, perfil: perfilUsuario)
        print("\(usuario.email) e \(usuario.nome) e \(usuario.uid) e \(usuario.perfil)")

        autenticacao.addStateDidChangeListener { (autenticacao, usuario) in
            if let usuarioLogado = usuario {

                print("Test")
            }
        }
     }

}
```

The result from the code above is

> ```
> Authenticated user Optional("NjZhCqk9pnSlTltfZl6oxa5vdd53")
> aa@gmail.com e aa e NjZhCqk9pnSlTltfZl6oxa5vdd53 e usuario
> Authenticated user Optional("NjZhCqk9pnSlTltfZl6oxa5vdd53")
> bb@gmail.com e bb e OzZjDzH1IyNE8IRQFAkqEgEUr5v2 e usuario
> Authenticated user Optional("NjZhCqk9pnSlTltfZl6oxa5vdd53")
> cc@gmail.com e cc e Y0WBAz6kEXQKMg3LjW4V2Vx8kzz1 e usuario
> ```

I'm looking to retrieve the "perfil" associated to the logged in user (not all of them) but, with my code I retrieve all users information.

How can I retrieve only the "perfil" from the current logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're reading all data under `usarios` and printing that. If you only want to read the data for the current user, you should observe that specific node. You do that by first determining the current user's UID, and then attaching the observer to that specific child node.

Something like this:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let database = Database.database().reference()
    let usuarios = database.child("usuarios")

    usuarios.child(uid).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        let dados = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let emailUsuario = dados?["email"] as! String
        let nomeUsuario = dados?["nome"] as! String
        let perfilUsuario = dados?["perfil"] as! String
        let idUsuario = snapshot.key

        let usuario = Usuario(email: emailUsuario, nome: nomeUsuario, uid: idUsuario, perfil: perfilUsuario)
        print("\(usuario.email) e \(usuario.nome) e \(usuario.uid) e \(usuario.perfil)")
     }
}
```

This will read the user's data from the database if they're logged in when the view is created. If you want to always load that data when they sign in, even if that is later, you'll want to use `addStateDidChangeListener`. Similar to how you already do, but you should attach the observer **inside** the callback/closure in that case.

Comment: Thanks Frank... that worked as I expected.. just make one change to the code
let usuarios = database.child("usuarios").child(uid)

Comment: Woops, good point. I had that at some point, but must've deleted it before submitting. I added it back, but in the line attaching the listener, as I'd prefer to not change the meaning of the `usuarios` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get firs the user id then read the specific child **let usuario = database.child("usuarios").child(idUsuarioLogado)**. if you are starting whit this project I recommend you to look Firestore, is way better.

> ```
> let autenticacao = Auth.auth()
> let idUsuarioLogado = autenticacao.currentUser?.uid
> // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
> let database = Database.database().reference()
> let usuarios = database.child("usuarios").child(idUsuarioLogado)
>
> usuario.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
>     ....
> ```

Comment: Thank Hugo.. that also worked. Just change one little thing "usuario.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in"